# How to crop and save segmented objects from an image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a hyperspectral image. In each image, there are many objects. I have to segment, crop, and save them as separate images. The segmented image after applying the thresholding is as below:

[image]

The problem is that I have to crop the segmented objects and save them. How it can be done?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** [Load the image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/), convert to [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html), and [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) to obtain a binary image.
2. **Remove noise.** We [morphological operations](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to remove any particles of noise in the image.
3. **Extract objects.** From here we [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), obtain each [bounding rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) then extract and save each ROI using Numpy slicing.

---

Detected objects

[image]

Saved ROIs

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph open to remove noise
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

# Find contours, obtain bounding box, extract and save ROI
ROI_number = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
    ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.waitKey()
```